# How to add a Header with value after a perticular column in linux

Tags: string, bash

Here I want to add a column with header name `Gender` after column name Age with value.

```
cat Person.csv

First_Name|Last_Name||Age|Address
Ram|Singh|18|Punjab
Sanjeev|Kumar|32|Mumbai
```

I am using this:

```
cat Person.csv | sed '1s/$/|Gender/; 2,$s/$/|Male/'
```

output:

```
First_Name|Last_Name||Age|Address|Gender
Ram|Singh|18|Punjab|Male
Sanjeev|Kumar|32|Mumbai|Male
```

I want output like this:

```
First_Name|Last_Name|Age|Gender|Address
Ram|Singh|18|Male|Punjab
Sanjeev|Kumar|32|Male|Mumbai
```

Comment: Are there actually two pipes `||` in the input file after `Last Name`?  P.S.: That's **not** a CSV file, it's pipe-delimited.

Answer (score 0):

I took the second pipe out (for consistency's sake) ... the `sed` should look like this:

```
$ sed -E '1s/^([^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|)/\1Gender|/;2,$s/^([^|]+\|[^|]+\|[^|]+\|)/\1male|/' Person.csv
First_Name|Last_Name|Age|Gender|Address
Ram|Singh|18|male|Punjab
Sanjeev|Kumar|32|male|Mumbai
```

We match and remember the first three fields and replace them with themselves, followed by `Gender` and `male` respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
$ awk -F"|" 'BEGIN{ OFS="|"}{ last=$NF; $NF=""; print (NR==1) ? $0"Gender|"last : $0"Male|"last }' Person.csv
First_Name|Last_Name||Age|Gender|Address
Ram|Singh|18|Male|Punjab
Sanjeev|Kumar|32|Male|Mumbai
```

Use '|' as the input field separator and set the output field separator as '|'.  Store the last column value in variable named `last` and then remove the last column `$NF=""`.  Then print the appropriate output based on whether is first row or succeeding rows.